# Library with SVM, EM and other methods with "weights per sample" like

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning

I have training samples of 2 classes with weights per sample and class weights. I trained SVC from sklearn.svm with good results on python using this code :

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
svc = SVC()
svc.class_weight = {0:1, 1:10}
svc.fit(trainSamples,trainLables,trainWeights)
```

Now I need to retrain my classifier on c++. I need library with SVM, EM and other methods with weights per each sample and class, can someone advise some libs ?

Answer (score 1):

A Support Vector Machine library that I've used many years ago, is **LIBSVM**, a C++ library from the Machine Learning Group at National Taiwan University. The latest version is 3.20 released on Nov 2014. LIBSVM also provides many extensions in various languages (Python included). ([link](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/)).

Another library I've used is **SVNLight**, written in C by Joachims Thorsten. ([link](http://svmlight.joachims.org/)).

Another option is the **OpenCV** API, that has a ***Machine Learning Library*** with SVM, EM, NN etc. (note that the SVM implementation is based on LIBSVM). Take a look to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/ml.html) page.